# What are the French equivalents of “light-headed” and “light-headedness”?

Tags: noms

If somebody is light-headed then [you feel weak as if you’re going to lose your balance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/light-headed).

According to Collins dictionary, the French equivalent of *light-headed* is [**étourdi(e)**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/light-headed). However, I’m unable to see how any of the definitions of **étourdi(e)** ([(1)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9tourdi/31524), [(2)](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/etourdi)) equal the English definition of *light-headed* given above.

So my questions are

1. Is **étourdi(e)** actually the French equivalent of *light-headed*? If so, please can you provide your source?
2. If yes, then is **« un étourdissement »** the French equivalent of
   *lightheadedness*?

Comment: Consider *étourdi* not as an adjective but as the past participle of *[étourdir](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%c3%a9tourdir/31528)*.

Comment: Thank you for your help @PeterShor . Unfortunately however, I’m failing to see how any of the definitions of **étourdir qn** equal **to make sb light-headed**.

Answer (score 4):

The adjective *[étourdi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tourdi/0)* has a very different meaning.

The past participle *[étourdi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tourdi/2)* is closer but is rarely used and seems to me a little too strong.

To describe this feeling, I'd rather use one of these idioms:

> *J'ai la tête qui tourne*.
> *Je suis dans le cirage.*
> *Je suis dans le brouillard.*
> *Je ne suis pas dans mon assiette.*
> *Je suis dans les vapes.*

About **light-headedness**, I think the most common translation would be *[malaise](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/malaise/1)*. Otherwise, you can also talk about *un léger étourdissement* or even *prémisse de [syncope](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/syncope)*.

There is also the literary *[pâmoison](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A2moison)* but it mostly has nowadays a figurative/teasing usage.

Comment: Also (slang): "Je suis dans les vapes"

Comment: @vc-74 Thanks! Added.

Comment: Thank you ever so much @jlliagre !  Do you know then the french equivalent for **light-headedness**?

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

**I**

*From the TLFi*

> **[étourdi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tourdi)** A.− [En parlant d'une pers.] Qui agit de façon irréfléchie, irraisonnée.

There is no other meaning to this word (except one derived from the preceding).

When you use this word in that sense, that is, as an adjective, you can use it as an "attribute" and as an "épithète"

- Jeanne est étourdie, elle ne se rappelle pas de chose faciles à mémoriser. (*attribut*)
- C'est une enfant étourdie. (*épithète*)

When you use the word "étourdi(e)(es)(s)" in the sense of being stunned, you are using not an adjective but the past participle of the verb "étourdir" and so, you can't use it as an "épithète".

- Jeanne était sur le sol, étourdie.
- Le coup l'a étourdie ; elle est étourdie.
- Je suis étourdi par tout cet alcool, <s>je suis un fêtard étourdi</s>.

Yes, the form "étourdi(e)(es)(s)" translate light-headedness, and it does that in both senses of "light-headedness". However, in each case it is not the same word: one is the adjective (thoughtless) and the other is only the past participle (stunned).

> (Robert Collins)  **light-headed** ADJ (=dizzy) étourdi, pris de vertige; (=exited) exalté, grisé; (=thoughtless) étourdi, écervelé

**II**

*From the TLFi*

> **[étourdissement](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tourdissement)** A.− MÉD. et usuel. Trouble provoqué par un choc moral ou physique et parfois caractérisé par une perte de conscience momentanée. Synon. défaillance, éblouissement, évanouissement, faiblesse.

Any other meaning is related to the preceding. Therefore, "**étourdissement**" is "**black out**", "**dizzy spell**". However, this word does not translate "a spell of light-headedness" when "ligth-headedness" means "thoughtlessness".

Comment: I’ve understood everything you’ve said so thank you ever so much @LPH  however **stunned* ≠ **light-headed**. If you type **define stunned** into Google, the definition given doesn’t equal the definition of **light-headed**.

Comment: @CubbyKushi Is "stunned" stronger than "slightly faint"? I've got "slightly faint" for "light-headed" in the OALD.

Comment: What is the OALD?

Comment: @CubbyKushi Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary

Comment: The definition of **stunned** given on Google is **so shocked that one is temporarily unable to react; astonished.** It’s stated at the very bottom that this definition is provided by *Oxford Languages*.

Comment: Regardless, I feel like I’m reading too much into this lol. I guess I’ll just have to take **light-headed** to equal **étourdi(e)**. Thank you for your help again! 

Comment: @CubbyKushi  I do have "dizzy", "giddy", "delirious" in the SOED. — It is maybe less strong than "stunned", but close.

Comment: What is the *SOED*?

Comment: @CubbyKushi The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary (abridged version of the OED).

Comment: @CubbyKushi I get finally that "stunned" is not exact; I'll change that, glad you caught it.

Comment: @CubbyKushi Yet I get in the SOED  "to stun: render unconscious. stunned: that has been stunned; dazed". So, I'll change nothing for now.

Answer (score 0):

Quand on consulte *Robert en ligne* au verbe [étourdir](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/etourdir) on trouve « Causer une ivresse, un vertige à (qqn). Le vin l'étourdit. [...]». Au [Larousse en ligne anglais-français](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/light-headed/592269) on divise les sens entre « dizzy » et « tipsy » et en question on ne précise pas si on traite d'un étiquetage de produit pharmaceutique ou de l'expression usuelle d'une sensation, lors de la consommation d'alcool par exemple, ni de son degré. Néanmoins on pense que « (je commence à ; j'ai des...) avoir des vertiges » et « ça [ou le nom : *vin, champagne* etc.] (ça commence à me ; ça me monte...) monter à la tête » peuvent être utiles. Si on en est *à la limite de l'évanouissement* plutôt qu'aux premiers symptômes, on peut aussi le dire. Le [nom](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/light-headedness/592270) (*[light-headed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/light-headed#English)ness*) pourrait aussi varier selon le contexte, de la « sensation de... » à un nom précis. On a aussi le nom [*faiblesse*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faiblesse) ([le plus souvent](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9F0091) au pluriel) pour « Défaillance ; évanouissement ; syncope » (Wiktionnaire) avec *avoir, tomber/partir* etc.